# Render Profile2 field out of Profile2 page

Tags: users

Is it possible to render one of Profile2 fields elswhere on the page, in some node ?

I would like to present user with opportunity to edit only one field on custom link or node.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Retrieve Profile2 Profile Data Programmatically**

- Implement [profile2_by_uid_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!contrib!profile2_page.module/function/profile2_by_uid_load/7)() to get the data.

  $profile2_data = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'profile_id');

$profile2_data will be an object containing all the data from profile_id for the requested user.

---

**Retrieve Profile2 Edit Form Programmatically**

```
module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');
$profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'profile_id');   // profile_id = machine name
$entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit');
return $entity_form;
```

Comment: Credit: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/125144/1082

Comment: When I did: `module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');`
`$profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'profile_id');` - I got function undefined - even though that `module_load_include` is meant to bring the function into scope. I used a different function as so: `$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user_from_csv->uid, 'main');` which worked on its own (without the `module_load_include`). This `profile2_load_by_user` function that I used belongs to the profile2 module rather than the

Comment: Credit: drupal.stackexchange.com/a/125144/1082