# How to programatically update existing user profile field in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, updating

We are using Drupal 7 and the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

We create and add a value to a field in the profile using this code:

```
$profile = profile_create(array('type' => 'main', 'uid' => $account->uid));
$lang = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$profile->field_headline[$lang][0]['value'] = 'Software Engg';
profile2_save($profile);
```

How can we programtically update the user profile field 'field_headline'?

Please advice us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to load the user using drupal function

```
profile2_load_by_user($account->uid, $type_name = NULL)
```

`$account->uid` => user id

`$type_name` => one of the profile types of profile 2 if any otherwise NULL

```
   $profile =  profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name = NULL)
   $profile->field_headline[$lang][0]['value'] = 'update Software Engg';
   profile2_save($profile);
```

For more information [Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1185912)

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: It is not working when i use for term refrence.

Comment: How would you change the profile2 type to something else?

Comment: This solution will not work in Drupal hooks such as hook_user_update().

Answer (score 0):

Update specific value of user

```
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);    
$user_fields->field_points['und'][0]['value'] = $points;

user_save($user_fields);
```